# How to read a temporary view created with Scala using R in Databricks?

Tags: python, r, scala, databricks, azure-databricks

I am new to Databricks and I am trying to read using R language a temporary table created with Scala. Before importing the table with Scala I stablished a connection to my company database. Here It is the code that I unsuccesfully used. I omitted the connection credentials with "xxxx". I know that I must use the sparklyr package to do this, so assume that I already loaded this package

```
%scala
val jdbcUsername = "xxxx"
val jdbcPassword = "xxxx"
val jdbcHostname = "xxxx" 
val jdbcPort = 9999
val jdbcDatabase ="xxxx"

import java.util.Properties

val jdbc_url = s"xxxx"
val connectionProperties = new Properties()
connectionProperties.put("user", s"${jdbcUsername}")
connectionProperties.put("password", s"${jdbcPassword}") 

val task = spark.read.jdbc(jdbc_url, "dbo.task", connectionProperties)
task.createOrReplaceTempView("task_temp")
```

```
teste = spark_load_table("task_temp")
```

The output error:

```
Error in UseMethod("hive_context") : Error in UseMethod("hive_context") : 
  no applicable method for 'hive_context' applied to an object of class "character"
```

I can read using python, like this:

```
%python
task_teste = spark.table("task_temp")
```

But as I mentioned, I need to read using R.

Comment: sql('select * from task_temp')

Comment: It does not work. I posted an answer to my own question .

Comment: This is why it pays to be explicit about your full environment -- `sql` is the function from the official Spark R package (`SparkR`), while `sdf_sql` is the analog from `sparklyr`

Answer (score 1):

I had success today doing this:

```
sdf_sql("SELECT * FROM task_temp")
```